# Validation Error on Transient Field of Model

Tags: java, forms, playframework

There is a Model A, which has a transient field; I do not want this field to be mapped by any column in the table.

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Entity
public class ModelA {

private String name;

@Transient
private int merchantIndex;


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getMerchantIndex() {
    return merchantIndex;
}

public void setMerchantIndex(int merchantIndex) {
    this.merchantIndex = merchantIndex;
}
}
```

While using the FormFactory to bind the model with the request data, I get a validation error on the Transient `merchantName` Field.

`Form<ModelA> modelForm = mFormFactory.form(mModelClass).bindFromRequest();`

I have tried declaring `@NotNull` Annotation, it also results in the same error `Validation Error` on the field.
It seems like a bug in the playframework, is there any workaround this problem?

Comment: 1) what error do you get? 2) are you using Scala or Java? (you added both tags)

Comment: Edited the question.